# How to make SQL injection in PostgreSQL's tsquery?

Tags: web-application, attacks, databases, sql-injection

I think there is SQL injection vulnerability in an application I'm testing. This is seen when I enter malformed parameters into a search form. All exceptions are shown in format:

```
PHP raised unknown error: pg_query() [http://php.net/function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "query" (more details about error - in log file)
```

So it looks like that PostreSQL's [tsquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY) function is used. After looking into some situations like:

```
The Fat & Rats:C
```

--> `ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "the & fat & & & rats:c"`

I think [plainto_tsquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES) is used to convert query into `tsquery`'s format.

To what extent might this vulnerability be exploitable? Is it secure to use those PostgreSQL functions without additonal sanitizing?

Comment: Informative error messages should be disabled and you should verify that the source code doesn't allow for SQL injection and is using bound parameters.

Comment: @drjimbob At this point, for this job, yes.  That is probably what he should do.  But, for future reference, it would be much better if he could learn to break such a weakness so that he can demonstrate the vulnerability to other customers.  I'm not saying we give a full-on "how to" on this (perhaps that should be removed from the question itself) - but some guidance as to whether or not it *is* an indication of an exploitable vulnerability (and to what degree, if determinable from given details), and perhaps some suggestions for further testing, may still be appropriate.

Comment: Edited the question a bit.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @drjimbob Understanding how to exploit vulnerabilities is on-topic and doesn't fall under the black hat restriction in the FAQ — this question isn't about how to carry out a specific attack. Besides the FAQ is more exclusive than the consensus on meta, which [we are working on fixing](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/897/clarify-our-stance-on-black-hat-questions).

Answer (score 4):

Looking [here](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=35043) which sounds pretty similar to what you're seeing, this isn't straight up SQL injection but rather an injection into the query language used in tsquery.  Also from the examples that may have been in a similar [closed] question, there was some oddness that didn't strike me as being a standard SQL Injection issue.

So not to say that it's not exploitable in some fashion, but that standard SQL Injection techniques are unlikely to produce useful results.